# Understanding the command pattern in essential js design patterns

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have a question regarding the [command pattern explanation](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#commandpatternjavascript) in the book - essential js designpatterns by addy osmani.

```
(function(){

  var carManager = {

    // request information
    requestInfo: function( model, id ){
      return "The information for " + model + " with ID " + id + " is foobar";
    },

    // purchase the car
    buyVehicle: function( model, id ){
      return "You have successfully purchased Item " + id + ", a " + model;
    },

    // arrange a viewing
    arrangeViewing: function( model, id ){
      return "You have successfully booked a viewing of " + model + " ( " + id + " ) ";
    }

    /* The function that acts as a common point for function calls */
    execute : function ( name ) {
      return carManager[name] && carManager[name].apply( carManager, [].slice.call(arguments, 1) );
    };

  };      

})();
```

Above is the code which is put as part of the explanation of the pattern. It would make the execute as the single entry point to the module which will get the appropriate methods called as per the arguments passed to it like.

```
carManager.execute( "arrangeViewing", "Ferrari", "14523" );
carManager.execute( "requestInfo", "Ford Mondeo", "54323" );
carManager.execute( "requestInfo", "Ford Escort", "34232" );
carManager.execute( "buyVehicle", "Ford Escort", "34232" );
```

#### Here my question is regarding the advantage mentioned for this pattern.

Quoting the book:

> If the core API behind the carManager changed. This would require all
>   objects directly accessing these methods within our application to
>   also be modified. This could be viewed as a layer of coupling which
>   effectively goes against the OOP methodology of loosely coupling
>   objects as much as possible. Instead, we could solve this problem by
>   abstracting the API away further.

As per the advantage above, `execute` method is the layer added as part of it. But as you can see, even the implementation of this additional layer of abstraction will require the method calls outside the module to be changed as the first parameter refers to the function name being called.

Suppose, an internal function of module changed from "arrangeViewing" to "arrangeViewing2", this will need all the dependent codes of this module to alter from

```
carManager.execute( "arrangeViewing", "Ferrari", "14523" );
```

to

```
carManager.execute( "arrangeViewing2", "Ferrari", "14523" );
```

unless we dont use a map inside execute function code, which point the function label to an actual function inside. So isn't the mentioned advantage pointless with the above code sample?

Also as per this code quoted above from book, we are not releasing `carManager` to outer scope for other modules to be able to use it. Also if we make execute as the single point of entry why couldn't other functions be private?.

Is my view correct or am I missing anything something important? Please help me out.

Comment: I don't personally see any advantage of `.execute()` over just calling the desired method directly.  As you point out, there's still just as much coupling and it's going to be slower.

Comment: The actual point of the command pattern is that commands are a serialisable data structure.

Comment: There doesn't need to be any tight coupling if the `execute` method doesn't map a method one to one from the `name` argument. I think the point Addy was making in the book remains that your determination logic belongs in the execute method, the name of the method is ultimately inconsequential but does require mapping.

Answer (score 5):

The decoupling via Command pattern is essential in the static typed languages like Java, c++, c#. But it is not so important in the dynamic typed languages like JavaScript because we can pass around any methods quite freely. So I also don't see advantages regarding this.

But Command has other characteristics that weren't mentioned in the book for example Command can serve as single source of truth for actions in the system and we can log what is going on in the system, we can create possibility for graceful rollback mechanics, create queues for commands if needed etc.

By the way whole Redux architecture is [actually Command pattern](https://medium.com/front-end-developers/the-command-pattern-c51292e22ea7#.llotzobax) where:

```
The Store = The Receiver
The Action = The Command
Dispatch = Executor
```

P.S. I found it useful to read Addy's book along GoF book.